# Laravel 5.7 Notification

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to build a notification system. But not a mail or sms notification. When I update a table in DB, user get web-browser notification(kind a facebook style) But I am little bit a stuck. I know Laravel has a system for this and when I search the internet people keep saying need pusher and tutorials all about e-mail notification. Not a database update and send web-message? What is the correct way to this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is Broadcasting

You can find more information about it here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting